# Will heroku run the python script added as web app foreever

Tags: python, heroku

I have pushed a python script,requirements.txt and a Procfile to Heroku and it is working fine when i
do

```
heroku run python script.py
```

the script.py contains a code that will execute completely only after a long time(say 2 days) till that time the code will be looping with few sleeps in between. So the question is whether the program will run forever or after few minutes will it crash. If it doesn't crash then what happens after executing the program for the first time will it start again?

I am new to using Heroku please bear with me if what I am saying is very wrong.Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The Heroku free plan has a limited amount of hours (550 in a month) and also the limitation that the Dyno will go to sleep after 30 min inactivity (which means no incoming HTTP requests).

If you need to run a background task for such a long duration you have the following options:

- keep the Web Dyno alive with an external script which invokes a URL of your application every 5-10 min (to prevent going to sleep)
- change to (paid) Hobby plan

PS
If you add a valid credit card you get an extra 450 hrs for free